# Difference between USE and USE [ ]

Tags: sql-server

I am running SQL Server 2014, and I am learning from examples.

I have created a database called `Sample` and I have several tables in it.

When I write a query I use either `USE [Sample]` or `USE Sample` command to make sure I will access the correct database.

I noticed that when I use the second command `Sample` has the same color as `USE` (blue), which is the color of every other SQL command e.g `INSERT`.

My question is what is the difference between these 2 commands?

Why `Sample` shows like a command in the second statement?

Comment: [] are just delimiters in case your db name is a reserved word or contains special characters

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so i guess it`s normal to see my db name in the same color as sql keywords.

Comment: If your database is called Sample, the coloring might be because sample is part of create statistics clause "... with SAMPLE x percent"

Comment: That makes things much clearer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use delimited identifiers (enclosed in brackets or double-quotes) only when the name doesn't conform to the regular identifier naming rules as described in the SQL Server Books Online: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874(v=sql.120).aspx.  One of the name restrictions is that the identifier must not be a reserved Transact-SQL keyword listed in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822(v=sql.110).aspx.

Note that SSMS will use color code keywords other than Transact-SQL reserved words.  Just because the name is color coded differently doesn't necessarily mean it must be enclosed.